# Wordpress theme functions not working when called

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a wordpress site and I want to save and do the database connection in my **functions.php**

So I can be calling it in my templates.
Here are the functions code in the in **functions.php**

```
<?php 

   function dbconnd() {

   $server = "localhost";
   $duser = "wpuser";
   $dpass = "wppass";
   $dbname = "wpdb";

   $conn = new mysqli($server, $duser,$dpass, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   }

?>
```

So in my main.php if I call `dbconnd();` , it seems it's not working as it throws a fatal error as in the case below:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /main.php on line 49

```
<?php
   dbconnd();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderform WHERE status='last';";
   $result = $conn->query($sql); //this is line 49
?>
```

But in case below when am not calling the function, it works perfectly

```
 <?php
   $server = "localhost";
   $duser = "wpuser";
   $dpass = "wppass";
   $dbname = "wpdb";
   $conn = new mysqli($server, $duser,$dpass, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderform WHERE status='last';";
   $result = $conn->query($sql); 
 ?>
```

Comment: You can run raw `SQL` using [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class. (`<?php $wpdb->query('query'); ?>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing right now, `$conn` is a local variable only inside the function. So you can't get the value outside the function that way.

The best solution would be this:

```
   function dbconnd() {

   $server = "localhost";
   $duser = "wpuser";
   $dpass = "wppass";
   $dbname = "wpdb";

   $conn = new mysqli($server, $duser,$dpass, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   else
   return $conn;

   }
```

And then when you're going to call the function, run this:

```
$conn = dbconnd();
```

Also don't forget to include or require the functions.php file inside the php file calling it.

Comment: It works now work perfect , I didn't include the require  functions.php , just $conn = dbconnd(); and including the return $conn made it, Thanks man